# MS ACCESS -Need to read and update

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Error: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information

I am trying to solve the following problem- getting my application to write back to my database.  The app is hitting the exception title listed above. I have been reading about database CRUD operations here- http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets12p7.html

I know from other reading I have done that I need to have a primary key.  Can someone explain how this relates when you are using a data set and data adapter?  Is this error related to my actual database or the in memory dataset?
I also realize that I have created a dataset based on one query.  Do I need a different query (INSERT) when I reach a ticket not found condition?

```
Private Sub BtnQuery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnQuery.Click

    sql = "SELECT [Ticket ID] AS Ticket_ID , [Foundstone] AS Foundstone, [ID] AS ID FROM [Table MAIN] WHERE ([Ticket Days OverDue] >= 0)" 'define the query
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "MAIN")
    If ds.Tables("MAIN").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        TxtRows.Text = ds.Tables("MAIN").Rows.Count
        maxrows = Val(TxtRows.Text.ToString)
    End If
    For i = 0 To maxrows - 1
        If i >= 0 Then
            result = ds.Tables("MAIN").Rows(i).Item("Ticket_ID")
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://fs-enterprise.my.private.url/remediation/ticket.exp?ticket=" & result)
            Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
                Application.DoEvents()
            Loop
            WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation = True
            '<div id="MessageGood_0" class="mvm-status-message msm-msg msm-msg-img" style="background-image:url(/images/fam/cross.png);">The specified ticket does not exist, or is not currently available.</div>  
            For Each el As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
                If (el.GetAttribute("id").Equals("MessageGood_0")) Then
                    TxtTicket.Text = ds.Tables("MAIN").Rows(i).Item("Ticket_ID")
                    'Try
                        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
                        cb.QuotePrefix = "[" 'allows update if table name or field is a reserved word in MS Access
                        cb.QuoteSuffix = "]" 'allows update if table name or field is a reserved word in MS Access
                        ds.Tables("MAIN").Rows(i).Item("Foundstone") = "Not Found"
                        da.Update(ds, "MAIN")
                        da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand()
        MsgBox("Ticket Not Found")
                    'Catch ex As Exception
                        'MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString, , "Error")
                    'End Try
                Else
                    '<input class="boldbutton" type="button" value="Verify" onclick="this.form.knob.value='ReqVerify';this.form.verify.value=1;this.form.submit()"></td>
                    TxtTicket.Text = ds.Tables("MAIN").Rows(i).Item("Ticket_ID")
                    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")
                        If (element.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Verify")) Then
                            element.InvokeMember("click")
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("All Tickets Have Been Processed")
    Me.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: The primary key needs to be set on the database table that you are accessing (`main` in this example). You shouldn't need a separate query to add a new row. You can add the row to your in-memory dataset and then update.

Comment: @theduck. Thanks, I understand the primary key needs to be in the table I am accessing.  I am trying to clarify this question in my mind- Does the key get set in the actual database or the dataset (the in memory representation of the database)?  I am not needing to add any additional rows of data, only write back to a column that has no data in an already existing row.

Comment: The primary key needs to be set on the actual database table rather than the in memory representation. If you don't need to add new rows you should be able to just update the dataset and commit the changes back to the database.

Comment: @theduck  Thanks for clarifying!  Now for part two of my question.  In my code above  I create a dataset that get iterated through and processed based on ticket #.  If the ticket is found a submit button is pushed.  If the ticket is not found I am trying to write back a "not found" value to the db in the Foundstone colum   So, I created my dataset based on one query but how do I write back?  Is that a separate Insert query that get placed in the "not found" logic in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that the primary key needs to be set on the actual database table rather than the in-memory dataset.

In answer to your second question, you can update the database from your dataset using the following:

```
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
ds.Tables("MAIN").Rows(i).Item("Foundstone") = "Not Found"
da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand()
da.Update(ds, "MAIN")
```

Comment: OK, now I get it!  Based on the code you provide you are passing the insert command back to the data adapter.  I should be able to fix the rest.  I am brand new to database programming and programming in general.  I only had one class in VB as part of my computer major.  (My major was networking not programming.)  So I am surprised I have done this well.  Many thanks for clarifying my questions.  This has brought my learning a new technology (new to me) full circle.  :-)

Comment: I guess I spoke a little too soon.  I made the edits as suggested.  I ran into a few more issues and fixed those.  Now, I don't have any exception errors thrown but I also don't see data being written to the source database either.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: ok swapped but still nothing.  I did  check my source database and the column field type is set to short text.

Comment: Also, remove your try/catch so you can see any errors.

Comment: Removed as shown above (assuming I understand you correctly)  Still no errors

Comment: Meant to say no errors and no updated source database

Comment: Just set this up on my machine and it runs just fine. Not sure I can help much more - case of debugging line by line I guess and making sure it is hitting the Update() command and that the dataset looks right at that point etc